# Do users have access to the Documents directory in an iOS sandbox?

Tags: ios, swift, filesystems, sandbox

I'm saving data that keeps track of a users virtual purchases inside the Documents directory of the app's sandbox. For obvious reasons I don't want the user to have access to this file or be able to manipulate it.

Is this the proper directory for storing these files? If not where can I store files that can not be accessed by the user?

I did find this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1) from Apple that suggests that data such as this should be stored in the Library directory. It doesn't seem to say if it's secure from users accessing it though.

Comment: What level of user are you protecting against? Decide on the attacker and attacker's skill level, basically it ranges from a teen to a well funded nation state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an iOS security expert, however, I can share my experience of working with users data on iOS. Any corrections/remarks are appreciated.

Generally speaking, the best recommendation would be to store important user's data remotely (i.e. having a server backend or using iCloud) with SSL-protected connection. However, if you are forced to store data locally for some reason, here are some recommendations:

1) Do not ever save important data in Documents directory or in `NSUserDefaults` **as is**. It's pretty easily accessible for user even on non-jailbroken devices. For instance, you can check iExplorer: as far as I remember, it does the trick.

2) If you really need to store some data locally, whatever your choice is: Documents folder, `UserDefaults` or `CoreData`, you have to encrypt it. Algorithm choice is up to you, but it's better to use some iOS built-in solution for it.

3) The data encryption assumes having a key for your app to decrypt it. The best way to store your key is **KeyChain**. Probably, that is the only place where you can store keys and other stuff like user's authorization data with no worries of being stolen from the outside.

Eventually, after all these steps your user's encrypted data can still be accessible by user. One won't be able to read it unless it is encrypted, but having access to the own keychain and some skill, an advanced user can finally get the original data. Moreover, it still can be damaged. So, in terms of saving data from being damaged or removed you still need to store backups or the data itself somewhere remotely.

Comment: A user has access to the keychain and that is the problem with encryption, protecting the key, you can't accomplish that on the device from the user but you can increase the work factor, that is make it more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You should treat data in the Documents directory as public.  Anyone with an iOS device hooked up to a computer via USB using a tool such as iExplorer or iFunBox can view the contents of your application's Documents and Caches directory.  For safety, consider using the keychain (if applicable), or a web service which validates the receipt (shared secret, user information, etc) to make sure that the user actually purchased the product, and isn't trying to spoof a transaction.

Comment: @zaph Any iOS device user with USB access to the phone, or technically anyone with a jailbroken device.  My point is that this information is not as private as people like to assume.  But you already knew that.